# Is EJB a good fit for a game server?

Tags: java, ejb

I have to do a university project that would consist of an EJB application and some remote client. I was thinking of developing a multiplayer game, preferably turn based. It would run on mobile devices and an application server would coordinate games, matchmaking, statistics and such.

Is EJB a viable solution for this? The biggest problem I see here is sharing the game state between different clients (session beans). When a player makes a move in the game, how would I push the state change to other clients?

Answer (score 0):

If you need no real-time experience it can work. It is reliable and designed to be usable over the web. You can simply try to fetch the gamestate changes from each client as it is done in regular browser based games.